# Find the complexity of longest common subsequence

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

```
for(int i = 1; i < str1.length(); i++)
{
    for(int j = 1; j < str2.length(); j++)
    {
        if(str1[i] == str2[j]) c[i][j] = c[i-1][j-1] + 1;
        else c[i][j] = max(c[i-1][j], c[i][j-1]);
    }
}
```

This is the algorithm, I need to find a time-complexity of this one. Let's assume that:

```
m = str1.length()
n = str2.length()
```

Thus it's obviously O(m*n).

But I have a couple of questions:

1. considering that comparisons, and assignments give 1 time-complexity, is this true that I'll have:

   O( 3*m*n*(3+1+2+2) )
   time complexity?
2. Is this possible to count worst-case, best-case, or average-case complexity here, if the array has to be fully assigned?

Comment: Constant factors are ignored for the complexity, `O(m*n)` is the same as `O(1000000000000000000000*m*n)`. Your algorithm is absolutely uniform, its best case is equal to its worst case.

Comment: @DanielFischer "Constant factors are ignored for the complexity" while true for big-O, that's not necessarily true for all complexity definitions.  In many contexts, complexity is measured by operation counts, in which case constants do matter

Comment: Even if you don't ignore constant factors, it is extremely naive to count operations in this way. For example, do you know how many instructions "if (str1[i] == str2[j])" is compared to "c[i][j] = c[i-1][j-1] + 1"? Are you sure whether the string length()s are cached or recalculated? So many things depend on language, compiler, runtime, architecture... This is why it is extremely misguided to count operations like that unless you know exactly what you're doing (low level optimization).